# How can I do this kind of Cholesky decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity

$B_{(n+1)(n+1)}$ = $       \begin{bmatrix}
        A & u \\
        u^T & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
        L_{11} & 0 \\
        L_{21} & l_{22} \\
        \end{bmatrix} $ $\begin{bmatrix}
        L_{11}^T & L_{21}^T \\
        0 & l_{22} \\
        \end{bmatrix} $

Here A is nxn matrix, $l_{22}$ is scalar, $L_{11}$ is also a nxn matrix.
So Cholasky factorization of this B matrix will give us the following:
$L_{11}*L_{11}^T=A, L_{11}*L_{21}^T=u, L_{21}*L_{11}^T=u^T$, and $L_{21}*L_{21}^T=1-l_{11}^2$

1. What to do after this?
2. Is the factorization done?
3. If this is done, how can I compute B's complexity(flops) if A is given - lets say it is N?

Thanks.

Comment: That's basically the outer product formulation of Cholesky decomposition. Watkins's book has a discussion on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, regarding 1, $L_1$ is computed as per the standard cholesky factorisation for $A$. Then from your working, you get $L_{21}^T=L_{11}^{-1}u$ and $l_{22}=\sqrt{1-L_{21}L_{21}^T}$.

For 2, now the factorisation is complete as you have determined what they factors should be.

For 3, the complexity for the determination of $L_{11}$ is known for the Cholesky decomposition. Then you just have to increment it for the additional computations which you incur.

Comment: so then $L_{11}$ should be such a matrix that its transpose is equal to itself.... does this tell you anything?  I guess symmetric

But then how can i decompose if matrix A is not given

Comment: If $A$ is not given, then you can't do anymore than I said, where $L_{11}$ is the cholesky factor of $A$. Once you know it, then you can extend the factorisation to an additional dimension, as I describe above.

Comment: OH, it says that Cholesky decomposition of A is given $A=L*L^T$, but then what does it mean $L_{11}L_{11}=L*L^T$ ?

Comment: You have a mistake. In the second matrix, the $(1,1)$ block should be $L_{11}^T$. Also, above, if $L_{11}L_{11}^T=LL^T$, then, $L_{11}=$?

Comment: ok thanks, how did i missed that ???

Comment: Here is a small problem. I got $L*L_{21}^T=u$. How write an answer for L21^T if L and u are given as it is. I cannot just write the answer as division right???

Comment: You (would) need an assumption stating that $A$ is not singular (assumed here), so that the Cholesky decomposition exists. If it does, then $L$ is invertible and this equation becomes $L_{21}^T=L^{-1}u$, which can be calculated once $L$ and $u$ are known.